# ‘In’ or ‘on’ + the act？

Tags: prepositions

> **In the last act**, a gaoler would always come on to the stage with a letter which he would hand to the prisoner.

> The curtain went up **on the final act** of the play and revealed the aristocrat sitting alone behind bars in his dark cell.

Before **the act**, sometimes we use **in**, and sometimes we use **on**. How to confirm which is to use in a occasion？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use '**in** a play, act or scene' when we are referring to something that happens in the course of the drama. (I'm not sure what you mean by *baller* - could it be a mistake for *jailer*?)

'The curtain rises/goes up **on**' is a particular expression referring to the scene that is revealed to the audience at the start of the play or of a new act.